# How to insert same reference multiple times in MS Word 2003?

Tags: microsoft-word, cross-reference

What I am trying to do is

>

> Information-1 <sup>1</sup>
>   Information-2 <sup>2</sup>
>   Information-3 <sup>1</sup>
>
> Reference list:
>
> 1. Reference-1
> 2. Reference-2

**But what I am getting is:**

>

> Information-1 <sup>1</sup>
>   Information-2 <sup>2</sup>
>   Information-3 <sup>3</sup>
>
> Reference List-
>
> 1. Reference-1
> 2. Reference-2
> 3. Reference-1

I have tried Reference-> Endnote, Reference-> footnote and Insert-> crossref. The crossref is showing a grey out insert button and I am confused of how to use this feature. Endnote and Footnoot is creating redundant reference as said above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s assume your notes are all footnotes and that you haven’t inserted any yet.

For the first footnote, use

```
Insert->Reference->Footnote...->Footnotes:
```

Then type the footnote text.

For the second footnote, repeat that, but with the appropriate footnote text.

For the third reference, use

```
Insert->Reference->Cross-reference...
```

In the dialog box, choose

Reference type: Footnote

Insert reference to: Footnote number (formatted)

And choose footnote 1 in the list under “For which Footnote”

And that should do what you need.